# Spring boot + apache tiles

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, apache-tiles

I'm trying to create that bean:

```
@Bean
public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
    TilesConfigurer configurer = new TilesConfigurer();
    configurer.setDefinitions("/tiles/tiles-definition.xml");
    return configurer;
}
```

I'm getting this problem:

> Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer'. Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   No URL for ServletContext resource [/tiles/tiles-definition.xml]

**tiles-definition.xml** is in `src/main/resources/static/tiles/` folder, but Spring cannot find it. What is the default root of webcontent?

When I used Spring MVC, it was `webapp/WEB-INF`, but I read that in Spring Boot it is `resources/static`, so I thought it is the root of every static web resource. Can you help me make that work?

Answer (score 0):

Path of resource seem to be wrong.

```
@Bean
public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
    TilesConfigurer configurer = new TilesConfigurer();
    configurer.setDefinitions("static/tiles/tiles-definition.xml");
    return configurer;
}
```

Comment: That was my first try. But it causes the same problem, I don't know what to do

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer'. Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No URL for ServletContext resource [/tiles/tiles-definition.xml]

Comment: Only difference is that it has [static/tiles/tiles-definition.xml] instead of  [/tiles/tiles-definition.xml]

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue today. Just packaging with WAR instead of JAR. Hope this help!